# How to add columns in TFS Sprints Taskboard (Not Online version of TFS)

Tags: tfs, state, sprint

I have a question about TFS. I want to add another column in Taskboard of Sprints board. I have ToDo, In Progress and Done columns and I want to add "In Test" Column before Done column. I could add another state to my project but I can't see that column in my Taskboard (I need it in Sprints view, not in Boards or Backlogs).why and how shoud i do for adding another column to my taskboard? I could do it in online version of TFS But I need this feature in server version. My process of project is scrum,too. Please help me to complete my project.
Best Regards,
Ali Khoeini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, seems you just want to add column in below page

[image]

Use these Steps:

1. Export work item (e.g. task) through WitAdmin command.
2. Add custom state to workflow section
3. Export ProcessConfiguration process file through WitAdmin command.
4. Add state item in TaskBacklog=>States section. For example:

   `<States>
     <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="In Test" />
     <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
   </States>`
5. Import modified work item file and process file to the team project
6. Check the result in web access.

*Note: If you are using TFS 2012, please change the version for export process configuration article to 2012. It is different.*

As for more details how to use WitAdmin command to export and import process configure file. Please refer our official tutorial here--[Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&redirectedfrom=MSDN) .The exported xml file could be edited through NotePad.

Comment: That adds a state to the work item to add a column in the kanban board, you can just click on the little gear symbol in the top right corner and navigate to column, from there you can add you column and keep the state to "in progress".

Comment: @Etienne Thanks for your sharing. But unlike with board for user story, it's not able to do this for sprint board  with task. It's also able to easily edit column from column options  in Azure DevOps Service. But still not able to do it in Azure DevOps Server/TFS.

Comment: Yup agreed Patrick, it's only for the requirement backlog.  I though that was is question, rereading it I see he mentions Sprint backlog.

Answer (score 0):

To only add a new column to your kanban board click on the gear in the top right corner of you board then go to columns and add the new column, keep the state to "in progress" and it should show up in your board.

Cheers